# How to diagnose /etc/hosts file having no effect

Tags: networking, network-manager, hosts

Right now, on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, for testing purposes I've changed the `/etc/hosts` file to something very simple:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   something
```

However, this simple configuration fails to appear in a `host` run:

```
$ host something
Host something not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`host` doesn't use `/etc/hosts` but only queries the DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` or given at the command line.

Comment: Very strange, as I have `8.8.8.8  google-public-dns` in my hosts file, and `host google-public-dns` does work `$ host google-public-dns
google-public-dns has address 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @Serg: `host -v google-public-dns` will tell you (among other things) from which server it got the answer.  Maybe you have a local DNS server that is reading `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @FlorianDiesch  `Received 51 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53`. That is indeed so. This could be `dnsmasq`.  My machine , however, should be using a custom dns set in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Comment: Found it. `dnsmasq` was set in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`,  and I thought I have disabled it. After disabling `dnsmasq` , the `host -v` command  started using dns set in `dhclient.conf` , and as expected it didn't read `/etc/hosts` file